# Calling IF Statement method in C#

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, if-statement, methods

I have noticed that I am repeating a lot of my code. What I want to do is store the below if-statement in a method so that it can be called at any time. My problem is, I understand methods, slightly, but I'm having difficulty creating a method for what i want. Below is an example of my code. The commented out code is the code i want to put in a method.Any help is much appreciated.

```
if (result.Equals("") && type == "")
{
    JObject jobj = JObject.Parse(Helper.callerClass(@""));
    var titleTokens = jobj.SelectTokens("...title");
    var values = titleTokens.Select(x => (x as JProperty).Value);

    /*if (titleTokens.Contains(s))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("");
    }*/
}
```

Comment: Google "c# method"

Comment: So make a method? What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
private bool Check(string result, string type) {
    if (result.Equals("") && type == "")
        {
            JObject jobj = JObject.Parse(Helper.callerClass(@""));
            var titleTokens = jobj.SelectTokens("...title");
            var values = titleTokens.Select(x => (x as JProperty).Value);

            return titleTokens.Contains(s);
        }
    return false;
}
```

You mean like this ?

Comment: you have to return something in case `!(result.Equals("") && type == "")` - i.e. if the very first `if` fails

Comment: Oh tanks, ye I coded it in the answer, forgot that :)

Comment: `return titleTokens.Contains(s);` instead of the last `if`

Comment: And why is it that the method "has" to return something ?

Comment: Cuz it has the bool in the definition, either it doesnt return anything at all, or always. So its either void or bool, string, etc

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear which code I wanted to put into a method. I have updated my question. Thanks.

Comment: Nowhere in the orignal post is indicated that it has to return something, just to show some messageboxes

Comment: Then make it a void and show the message boxes, where the problem ?!

Answer (score 0):

```
//To call the function use the following line and replace yourClassName with you class name
  yourClassName myInstObj= new yourClassName();
  myInstObj.Check(result,type);

//Copied from the above answer b/c it should work fine.

private bool Check(string result, string type) {
   if (result.Equals("") && type == "")
    {
        JObject jobj = JObject.Parse(Helper.callerClass(@""));
        var titleTokens = jobj.SelectTokens("...title");
        var values = titleTokens.Select(x => (x as JProperty).Value);

        if (titleTokens.Contains(s))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Why explicitly return true and false? Why not just directly return the result of the Contains method?